# How to use IPython.notebook.kernel.execute in Azure databricks?

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, databricks, azure-databricks

I have built an HTML JS based UI within azure databricks notebook 
While trying to call a python function using kernel i keep getting IPython isnt available.

```
%%javascript
function call_python_fn(cmdstr){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    var callbacks = {
        iopub: {
            output: (data) => resolve(data.content.text.trim())
        },
        
        shell: {
            reply: (data) => resolve(data.content.status)
        }

    };
    IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(cmdstr, callbacks);
});
}

var tmp = 2;
call_python_fn('print('+tmp+')').then((resolve)=>alert(resolve));`
```

Above snippet perfectly works fine in conda Jupyter notebook, what is alternative to kernel execute in Azure databricks?

Comment: Were you able to obtain any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `iPython` or any of the Ubuntu packages in the following way.

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install ipython3 -y
```

And then run your javascript code